# How to externalize mongo db queries

Tags: mongodb

I want to externalize complete mongo db query.

I know that we can externalize by splitting query into **$project**, **$filter** ,**$sort** and so on...

But I want the whole query to be externalized.

For example,

```
db.employee.find({dept:'FINANCE'},{empId:1,empName:1,empDesn:1}).sort({empSal:1}),
```

Here I want to externalize this mongo query, please share your thought how to achieve it using java.

Comment: What do you mean by "externalize the query"?

Comment: I want to push these mongo queries into a properties file and read from there, rather than actually having them in the java code.

Comment: And why would one do that?

Comment: To keep java code unaltered for query changes. If it is in a properties file, any future modifications to the query will be made into properties file and that way Java code will not require changes changes and hence saves compilation overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I connect to mongodb using java for read and right. We use mongo-java-driver-2-XX.jar to connect it

sample code is :

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;

 public class MongoDBJDBC{
   public static void main( String args[] ){
     try{   
         // To connect to mongodb server
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
     // Now connect to your databases
     DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
     boolean auth = db.authenticate(myUserName, myPassword);
     System.out.println("Authentication: "+auth);
  }catch(Exception e){
     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
    }
 }
}
```

For more details check this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_java.htm)

Comment: Question here is, how to externalize these mongo queries not connecting to mongodb from java.

Comment: externalise means i assume executing queries right. please check the link shared